# Why do the wrong parts of my character move when I move a bone?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, weight-painting, tracking

When I pose my character's arm, his hair and "ear communicator" and sometimes the visor of his hat move with the arm. Also when he kicks, his shoe/foot detatches from the mesh. I joined him altogether in one object. Any idea why he is acting like that?

[image: messed up arm]

[image: messed up shoe]

[image: regular]

[image]

Comment: Hey, welcome to the forum! Have you checked your weight painting in wireframe mode? Sometimes maybe there will be some weight left in an area because it was not reachable by the brush in solid mode. Other than that, I'd suggest uploading some images and the .blend file.

Comment: Ok, i will upload some images. I tried weight painting, but after, when I tried to move my character's bones his leg got all twisted up and gnarled. It was pretty weird. How do I share a blend file?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ by using this website

Comment: Just did it! Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can see from your pictures, it looks like the joints are not connected to each other like they should. But it's very hard to tell. The blend file would be very useful!

Comment: I put a link to the blend in the description

Comment: Ok, I've opened the file. It seems as if your bones are not connected properly. When you move the lower leg, the foot wants to stay in place. I'm not much of an expert on weight painting though, so possibly someone else can help you further. At least they have the resources to do so now :)

Comment: Ok, Thank you Hedriks! You taking the time to help me means alot!